# Settings.Gobal class is not working in Android 4.2.2?

Tags: java, android

I am using above class to display following result:

```
AIRPLANE_MODE_ON=0
AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS=cell,bluetooth,wifi,nfc,wimax
```

The code i used is as follow:

```
Log.d("Airplane_mode_on",Settings.Global.getInt(mcontex.getContentResolver(), Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON))
Log.d("Airplane_mode_radios",Settings.Global.getString(mcontex.getContentResolver(),Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_RADIOS))
```

In Logcat, it shows "Class Not Found Exception". When i read the documentation of Settings.Global, it says this class is compatible with    API 17. Any Suggestion?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17049778/485288

Comment: @Cloudream In my code, Settings.Secure class and Settings.Sytem class works absolutely fine. Only issue is with this class which i don't understand