# How to know if Airplane Mode is TURNED ON or TURNED OFF in BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have seen multiple answers in other questions with this solution to know if airplane mode changed:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new      
IntentFilter("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED");

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("AirplaneMode", "Service state changed");
      }
};

context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

But now I want to know if the Air Plane Mode is turned ON or OFF on onReceive method.

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4319212/

Answer (score 5):

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17049778/1638739), you can check airplane mode state by:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
public static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {        
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;          
    } else {
        return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
                Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
    }       
}
```

if the returned result is `true`, so airplane mode is **ON**, and vice versa, so your complete answer would be:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new      
IntentFilter("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED");

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("AirplaneMode", "Service state changed");
            boolean airplane_active = isAirplaneModeOn(context);
      }
};

context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new      
IntentFilter("android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED");

BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("AirplaneMode", "Service state changed");
            boolean isAirplaneMode = isAirplaneModeOn(context);
      }
};

context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);

private static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {

   return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
           Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;

}
```

#### Note

In Jelly Bean 4.2, this setting has moved to `Settings.Global`

Comment: Prefer using the constant in the Intent class. Which as of Android 10 is `public static final String ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED = "android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE";`

Answer (score 0):

by using ContentObserver also we can get

```
private class SetupContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

private final Uri mDeviceProvisioned = Settings.Global.getUriFor(
        Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON);

public SetupContentObserver(Handler handler) {
    super(handler);
}

void register() {
    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(mDeviceProvisioned, false, this, UserHandle.USER_ALL);
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri, int userId) {
    // do actula logic
}
```

}