# Xamarin.Forms - How to determine if your ios or android device is in airplane mode?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

How can I detect if the phone (ios or Android) is in airplane mode?  The Connectivity class in Xamarin.Essentials doesn't actually tell.  I have seen some questions on stack overflow that answer it for older versions of Android.  But I am wondering if there is a new better way to do that which also includes ios?

Comment: I find one article about using Xamarin.Essentials to check Mobile device connectivity, you can take a look:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/easily-check-mobile-device-connectivity-with-xamarin-essentials/

Comment: I am using that library in my app and it works well.  But there doesn't seem to be a way to determine if the user put the phone in airplane mode or if the user is in a area with no wifi or cellphone coverage.

Comment: I search some info, maybe you can use  intentFilter to detect current airplane mode status:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319212/how-can-one-detect-airplane-mode-on-android